# Angular application unable to find scripts due to invalid paths

Tags: angular

my angular application is returning 404 for all of my scripts

if i click on a link that takes me to a page at url: "domain/shopping/

it sends an HTTP request for "domain/shopping/main.js"

that fails every time because the script is at this location : "domain/main.js"

I've tried changing the base href to "." and "./" and "../" with no luck.

how do i just make my app always look for the scripts in the root?

Comment: What code have you written? Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config

I think you need to add the `.js` files to the `scripts` array in `.angular.json`.